# Django 1.8 model form fields not showing when rendering template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form which will allow users to input data into my database. I have followed many tutorials which may have lead to my confusion. The problem is that my page is showing up with all the html elements, but the form is not being displayed. I have no idea why. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    #forms for blocks  
    from django import forms
    from .models import Block
    class BlockForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Block
            fields = ['block_status', 'block_name', 'block_derivatives',  'block_subsystems', 'owners']

    # def requests view.py
    def requests(request, inventory_id):
        inventory = get_object_or_404(Inventory, pk=inventory_id)
        #return render(request, 'inventory/requests.html', {'inventory':      inventory})
        form = BlockForm()
        if request.POST:
            form = BlockForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                form.save()
                print"FUFUFUFUFUF"

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory/2')
            else:

                form = BlockForm()
                print "LOLOLO"
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))

            args['form'] = form

            return render_to_response('requests.html', args)
        print "HIHIHIHIHIH"
        return render(request, 'inventory/requests.html', {'inventory':  inventory})

    # urls
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^(?P<inventory_id>.*)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^(?P<inventory_id>[0-9]+)/requests$', views.requests,   name='requests'),
        #url(r'^(?P<inventory_id>.*)block_form/$', views.block_form)
    ]

#requests.html

     <div class="blockform">
         <div class="container">
             <form action="{% url 'inventory:requests' inventory.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <ul>
                <li>Hello, world.</li>
                {{form.as_table}}
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Blocks">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the form to the template if the request is a GET. There's really no need to distinguish between the GET and POST in this case when creating the form instance. You can simply instantiate your form as such:

```
form = BlockForm(request.POST or None)
```

and drop the instantiation after the `if request.POST`. I'm also not sure why you're using `render_to_response` if it's a POST vs `render` on the GET. You can use `render` in both cases.

Your view really only needs to be:

```
def requests(request, inventory_id):
    inventory = get_object_or_404(Inventory, pk=inventory_id)

    form = BlockForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory/2')

    return render(request, 'inventory/requests.html',
        {'inventory':  inventory, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Ok, how do i pass the form to my template exactly? I am not seeing the connection between the two. Also, what did you mean by dropping the instantiation of request.POST? I just commented it out. How should that if statement be corrected? I reran the the server and the form still doesn't display. I am not getting any errors either. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow it works now. Thank you! Could you explain what {'inventory': inventory, 'form': form} does? Also, does form.save() save new data to my database after validating?

Comment: The dictionary containing the variables is referred to as the template context. ModelForms have a `.save ()` method to persist the data and return the newly created object. Have you worked through the official Django tutorial? If not, it's well worth your time.

Comment: You're referring to this one right?  I have but I really raced through it in an effort to try to finish this project the first time. I am actually going through it a second time. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: fwiw, I did that tutorial and I had the same question. This answer was much clearer than the tutorial.